# How to programatically add cron job via telnet?

Tags: ubuntu, cron, telnet, telnetlib

I have Machine-1 and Machine-2 connected via LAN. I want to create a program that see if number of jobs scheduled in Machine-1 exceeds certain limit then to schedule upcoming jobs in Machine-2 so to avoid overhead from single machine. Both Machines has Ubuntu OS.

I already can count the number of job scheduled in machine-1. Just not getting the way how could i install job in another machine.

How can i achieve this setup?

Is it possible to be done via TELNET? Or Any suggestions??

Any help/hint/solution will be appreciated.

Best Regards,
MD Danish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is create a script on Machine-2 which counts the jobs (you seem to have already done that). Then, from Machine-1, call that scripts via SSH and do something useful with the results.

Example script on Machine-1:

`` !#/bin/bash
result=`ssh user@machine2 /data/scripts/countJobs.sh` 
...do something with result... ``

Comment: I need to edit my question, I am taking database help in intermediate, I am able to install and count the jobs of same machine but not another machine...

Comment: Could you explain how you count the jobs on Machine-2 then?

Comment: Yes correct! Can we send the parameter in remote call? In this case better i will send the cron path as a parameter and upload the script file?

Comment: Sure, adding parameters would just be `ssh user@machine2 /data/scripts/countJobs.sh param1 param2` etc...

Comment: I have one centralized database from there I can monitor the number of cron jobs scheduled for that particular machine. Also By Counting the number of new lines present in Crontab.

Comment: Then How can i upload the file to that machine via such kind of remote call?

Comment: What file do you want to upload?

Comment: I'm still unsure what you're referring to. Can you please describe the transfer of the file (from Machine-1 to Machine-2? The other way around?) and why it is needed?

Comment: I have written crawler algorithm to search in web for the links. Every time Script used to assign a couple of links to each spider and install the spider as cron job. This way my script is single machine centric. But now I am 90% clear with what to do next... Your help has made me clear... Tammert

Comment: Awesome :). Good luck!

Comment: I am just wondering if i can upload via scp but without manual entering password?

Comment: You have to set up SSH keys on both machines. See the following link for a tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys--2

Comment: No problem! If my answer helped, please mark it as the answer to the question :).

Answer (score 0):

You can make some remote call using ssh (telnet is not recommended as it's not secure). Just type `ssh login@host [command]`. To play with cron I use (on Fedora and Centos) `crontab -e` .

Comment: Thanks +jaroslawj for the kind answer.

Comment: Is there a way to upload the file via ssh remote call?

Comment: Not ssh directly, but you can use scp.

Comment: I got that ... Thanks

Comment: I am just wondering if i can upload via scp but without manual entering password? Something like pragmatically???

Comment: Yes, but you should export your public key firstly. Generate new key with ssh-keygen if you don't have one already, and next copy it to the remote host - i.e using ssh-copy-id

Comment: Okay ... I don't have a reputation to vote up for your answer.. Anyway Thanks a ton